# Can Google repo report on current branch being ahead of remote?

Tags: git, repo

In a single `git` repo I can do:

```
<project2 root dir>$ git status
On branch feature/feature_release
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/feature_release' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Using `repo`, though, I get:

```
$ repo status
project <project1 root dir>/ branch feature/feature_release
project <project2 root dir>/ branch feature/feature_release
project <project3 root dir>/ branch feature/feature_release
```

This doesn't tell me that, for instance, that `project2` has local changes requiring pushing. If I try `forall` I get this:

```
$ repo forall -c "git status -sb"
...
## feature/feature_release...origin/feature/feature_release [ahead 1]
## HEAD (no branch)
## feature/feature_release...origin/feature/feature_release
## feature/feature_release...origin/feature/feature_release [ahead 1]
## feature/feature_release...origin/feature/feature_release [ahead 1]
## feature/feature_release...origin/feature/feature_release
## HEAD (no branch)
## HEAD (no branch)
...
```

Is there a built-in way with `repo` to do something like prepend the project name:

```
## <project1 root dir>/ feature/feature_release...origin/feature/feature_release [ahead 1]
## <project2 root dir>/ HEAD (no branch)
## <project3 root dir>/ feature/feature_release...origin/feature/feature_release
## <project4 root dir>/ feature/feature_release...origin/feature/feature_release [ahead 1]
```

I suppose beginning with `repo start` would help, but I never got that to work usefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I RTFMed a bit further, and the `-p` flag seems to be most of what I am looking for:

```
$ repo forall -pc "git status -sb"
...
project <project1 root dir>/
## feature/feature_release...origin/feature/feature_release [ahead 1]

project <project2 root dir>/
## HEAD (no branch)

project <project3 root dir>/
...
```